# PlayOnLinux - gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, linux-mint, gnome, wine

While trying to launch a game with PlayOnLinux it crashes and I find this in the debugger:

```
[01/28/16 09:20:18] - Running wine-1.9.2-LeagueOfLegends5 lol.launcher.admin.exe (Working directory : /home/richusx/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends/drive_c/Riot Games/League of Legends)
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directoryp11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directoryp11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

ls -all of the pkcs11 directory

```
richusx@Prometheus /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11 $ ls -all
total 228
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Jan 28 09:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 41 root root  32768 Jan 28 09:02 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     56 Jan 28 09:17 gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so -> /usr/lib32/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 190660 Mar 20  2014 p11-kit-trust.so
```

I've installed: *winbind; p11-kit:i386;* but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by installing "libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386"